# Best practises: Applying iptables firewall rules for SSH

Tags: rhel, iptables, firewall

I need to add some firewall rules in our QA environment using `iptables`. I have to do the changes remotely . Some of the changes also include disabling `SSH` for few Networks .

What are best practices I can follow so that if `SSH` service is somehow get blocked , how can I restore my access back without rebooting the host.

Some of the things I am planning are:

```
chkconfig iptables off
```

This is in case if we need to reboot the host , so that `iptables` is not started up.

But this is for when we reboot for host , I am looking for something so that we can restore back without rebooting the host . BTW , `console` is not available for the server.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `iptables-apply` is for. From the [man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=iptables-apply&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en):

```
iptables-apply will  try  to  apply  a  new  rulesfile  (as  output  by
   iptables-save,  read by iptables-restore) or run a command to configure
   iptables and then prompt the user whether the changes are okay. If  the
   new  iptables  rules  cut the existing connection, the user will not be
   able to answer affirmatively. In this case, the script  rolls  back  to
   the previous working iptables rules after the timeout expires.
```

The default timeout is 10 seconds. If this is too short it can be changed with `--timeout 30` to reset the rule after 30 seconds if no confirmation has been received.

Comment: I think we can also set a cron job which will disable  iptables  after few minutes and after that we can remove my incorrect firewalll rules

Comment: @ZamaQues Sure, a few lines of shell script and you can bake your own solution which will reset the state. But why replicating the work if others have already solved the problem and made a tool for this?

Comment: This question is tagged with `rhel`, but `iptables-apply` is not included with RHEL.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I usually take for a task like this is to ensure that I have a failsafe rule at the very beginning of the `INPUT` chain that explicitly permits my existing management connection. That will ensure that any subsequent rules that might prevent a connection won't affect the current one. Once I have all rules in place, I then test it with a second connection that should be accepted, but that doesn't match the failsafe rule. If that works, I know I can safely disconnect my original session and remove the failsafe rule.

For example, let's say you want to permit SSH from 192.168.0.0/16, except for 192.168.2.0/24, and you're currently connected to the server from 192.168.22.22. To guard against a possible typo, you might set your rules up like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.22.22  --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp                   --dport 22 -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.2.0/24 --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.0.0/16 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

In this case, we insert the first rule with `-I` so it's at the very beginning of the chain, and we append the others with `-A` so they get tacked onto the end. Your rules are probably more complex than this, but the point is to ensure that your failsafe rule comes first. In this way, even if you mistakenly enter 192.168.22.0/24 on the second line, your failsafe line will match first, ensuring that you retain access.

Test the rules by trying to connect from somewhere in 192.168.0.0/16 that isn't 192.168.22.22 or 192.168.2.0/24. Regardless of the outcome, it should get logged to `/var/log/kern.log`. If the connection fails, you'll know you have more work to do; the log may help you determine why it failed as well.

Once your testing succeeds, you can safely remove the failsafe rule:

```
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.22.22 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```